# Encapsulate a function with another function that has the same set of parameters

Tags: function, c++11

I have a function that has a lot of parameters. (4-7 parameters)

For simplicity, this is an example:-

```
class B{
    friend class C;
    int f(int param1,float param2, structA a, structB b){
         //... some code ...
    }
    //.... other functions ....
};
```

Sometimes, I want to **encapsulate** it under another (more-public) function that has the same signature:-

```
class C{
    B* b;
    public: int g(int param1,float param2, structA a, structB b){
        return b->f(param1,param2,a,b);
    }
    //.... other functions ....
};
```

In my opinion, the above code is   :-

- tedious
- causes a bit of maintainability problem
- human error-prone

Is there any C++ technique / magic / design-pattern to assist it?

In the real case, it happens mostly in edge-cases that **composition** is *just a little* more suitable than **inheritance**.

I feel that `<...>` might solve my problem, but it requires **template** from which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

> but it requires template from which I want to avoid.

That's, in my opinion, the wrong mindset to have. You should avoid templates if you have a very good reason to do so, otherwise you should embrace them - they are a core feature of the C++ language.

With a *variadic template*, you can create a perfect-forwarding wrapper as follows:

```
class C{
    B* b;
public: 

    template <typename... Ts>
    int g(Ts&&... xs){
        return b->f(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...);
    }

};
```

The above `g` *function template* will accept any number of arguments and call `b->f` by perfectly-forwarding them.

*(Using `std::forward` allows your wrapper to properly retain the value category of the passed expressions when invoking the wrapper. In short, this means that no unnecessary copies/moves will be made and that references will be correctly passed as such.)*

Comment: (sad face)  With template, I can't move it to .cpp  -> compile time increase & other bad side effects.

Comment: @javaLover: unless your code is heavily-templated and full of compile-time metaprogramming the impact of adding some wrapper templates will be **unnoticeable** in terms of compile-time. Please clarify *"other bad side effects"*. Also clarify *"I can't control which function I want to expose"*.

Comment: I can't control which function I want to expose  <--- I am wrong (please forget it)

Comment: other bad side effects = circular dependency (it is not so much problem) .....   Sometimes, I encapsulate for pimpl, so in that case, all will be lose. (sorry, I didn't mention it explicitly)

Comment: ...do you really need *PImpl* here? It [has its own drawbacks](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl). I might be wrong, but to me it sounds like you're unnecessarily trying hard to avoid templates and anything that *could* increase compilation time. That can be reasonable, but: **have you measured the impact of adding a template on compilation time?** If not, you should, and then draw your conclusions. Also, **PImpl** is trading run-time for compilation-time - there is some overhead as seen in the page I linked.

Comment: There are some workaround to not sacrifice run-time by sacrificing a bit of maintainability ....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921932/pimpl-idiom-without-using-dynamic-memory-allocation  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769057/heap-free-pimpl-incorrect-or-superstition?rq=1 .   (I didn't test it yet.)  Good point about "you should measure", thank.

Comment: @javaLover If you are pimpl wrapping, then the definition of `f` isn't visible in the header; `g` cannot be dependent on `f`'s definition if you are hiding `f` at the point of `g`'s definition.

Comment: One case where the template cannot be used for this : if the function use a forward declared class.

Answer (score 1):

In a public header:

```
using f_sig = int(int param1,float param2, structA a, structB b);

class hidden;
class famous {
  hidden* pImpl
public:
  f_sig g;
};
```

In your .cpp:

```
class hidden {
  friend class famous;
  f_sig f;
};
```

Now, you cannot use this pattern to *define* what `f` or `g` does, but this does *declair* their signatures.  And if your definition doesn't match the declaration you get an error.

```
int hidden::f(int param1,float param2, structA a, structB b) {
  std::cout << "f!";
}
int famous::g(int param1,float param2, structA a, structB b) {
  return pImpl->f(param1, param2, a, b);
}
```

type the signatures wrong above, and you'll get a compile-time error.

Comment: I have never seen "using" like that before.  That saves around 1/3 of the duplication, thank.

Comment: @javaLover It is just a fancy `typedef` above.  The typedef syntax for functions is awkward, so I use `using`.